# Pass array as inputs to Azure DevOps YAML task

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I'm trying to configure a CI that will produce NuGet packages as artifacts on Azure DevOps (that will be later pushed to my NuGet server).

For this, I'm using Builds Pipelines on Azure DevOps, the YAML version.

I have 3 projects that should build packages. I'm using [NuGetCommand@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) to accomplish this task :

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/HTS_MessageEngine.Communication/HTS_MessageEngine.Communication.csproj
    majorVersion: $(majorVersion)
    minorVersion: $(minorVersion)
    patchVersion: $(patchVersion)
    versioningScheme: byPrereleaseNumber
```

However, I have to duplicate this block 3 times, for each project. Is there a way to specify an array of projects in the packagesToPack parameter? So far, the version is the same for each package, so I don't need three different blocks...

*Note: these 3 projects are all 3 NetStandard and properties for package building are stored in csproj directly*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use each function (if its available at all at this point in time):

```yaml
# my-template.yml
parameters:
steps:
- ${{ each project in parameters.projects }}:
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: Publish ${{ project }}
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ project }}.zip'
```

```yaml
# ci.yml
steps:
- template: my-template.yml
  parameters:
    projects:
    - test1
    - test2
```

Github PR for this functionality: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/pull/2#issuecomment-452748467

Comment: Wow that's awesome ! Thanks !

Comment: @cdie where is parameters.project defined? I dont see any 'project'

Comment: Is it necessary to have a template file? Could you just do it all in one yaml file?

Comment: never tried that, the whole point of the template is to have a separate template to reuse it, but if you scan azure devops yaml docs you might find examples of this in one file, i think

Comment: There is a ticket with MS about this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812728/variables-in-yaml-pipeline-are-not-allowing-to-def.html

Comment: @pradeep, i edited the code to include the "projects" node that was missing and has been working very nicely for me... i use it for stages so far, we can even do conditional logic to include/exclude items in these lists... very powerful to have a generic array construct available to us in the pipeline syntax, i believe it's called a "sequence" in msft's pipeline vernacular... the msft github sample this was pulled from is wrong as well... maybe this spec changed since these examples were created

Comment: Can you pass an Object to foreach? I need mote then 1 parameter. For example: x86+Release, x86+Debug,x64+Release,x86+Debug.

Answer (score 13):

For above code I got this exception running a build:

```
my-template.yml (Line: 1, Col: 12): Unexpected value ''
```

but this works for me:

```yaml
# my-template.yml
parameters:
- name: projects
  type: object
  default: {}
steps:
- ${{ each project in parameters.projects }}:
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish ${{ project }}
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ project }}.zip'
```

and then:

```yaml
# ci.yml
steps:
- template: my-template.yml
  parameters:
    projects:
    - test1
    - test2
```

Comment: I am trying something similar, but getting error while triggering the job, any help would be appreciated.

# batch.yml
steps:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    repos:
    - 'a-b-c'
    - 'x-y-z'

Comment: ## template.yml##
variables:
  brancName: $(Build.SourceBranchName)

parameters:
- name: projects
  type: object
  default: {}
steps:
- ${{ each repo in parameters.repos }}:
  - task: TriggerPipeline@1
    displayName: 'Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline: Build'
    inputs:
      serviceConnection: 'Azure_DevOps_API_Connection'
      project: ABC
      Pipeline: 'Build'
      buildDefinition: '${{ repo }}-build-k8s'
      buildRepo: '${{ repo }}'
      Branch: $(brancName)

  - task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'sleep 120'

Comment: @Devops-Learner could you create a separate question for this?